# Convert varchar to integer and sort in a MySql query

Tags: mysql

A column in table has numbers stored as varchar. Some values have > sign (e.g, >128).

First, I want to strip the > sign.

Next, convert them to integers and retrieve data on that column by sorting in ascending order. I am using IF condition to strip the > sign and then using cast function to convert.

I am using the following lines, which is throwing up error:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax**

```sql
SELECT CAST((if(col_name ='>128',128,col_name) as MIC) AS UNSIGNED) 
FROM `mytable` order by MIC ASC
```

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: there must be more information. Can you provide the whole error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(col_name,'>') = 0 THEN CAST(SUBSTR(col_name,2) as UNSIGNED) 
       ELSE CAST(col_name as UNSIGNED) END as MIC
FROM mytable
ORDER BY MIC
```

Comment: Thanks. I tweaked my own line and got the desired results. The following works: `code`SELECT CAST((if(col_name ='>128',128 ,col_name)) AS UNSIGNED) as MIC FROM my_table order by MIC ASC `code`